# Exporting Sketch Artboards to InVision via Craft

Tags: sketch-app

I marked an Artboard to be exported (as PNG, also tried PDF) to be exported to InVision and then syncing the Sketch file via the Craft plugin. I was expecting the Artboard to show up in the assets of the InVision prototype. But they are not. Any help on this? Or are full Artboards only exportable manually?

[image: Export options]

Is there anything else I might have forgotten?

Answer (score 1):

[image: Sketch's InVision Craft toolbar Sync menu]

Whether you're trying to Sync a single artboard, multiple selected artboards, or all the artboards on a single page, you'll want to use the `Sync` panel within the Craft plugin.

---

[image: Syncing to a prototyping with InVision's Craft toolbar in Sketch]

You'll need to `Create or select a prototype…` and then you'll be able to `Sync to InVision`.